# Use a class object in JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I have created an object(class) in java and want to use it in jsp page

my jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.anshu.obj" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        obj fooBar = new obj();
        System.out.println("Name is "+fooBar.nameOwener());
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

and my class is

```
package com.anshu;
public class obj {
    public String nameOwener(){
        return "Anshu";
    }
}
```

---

### but it gives error

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.anshu.obj resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /index.jsp

### obj cannot be resolved to a type

Thanks in advance :)
I am dummy to jsp
i am using jboss 7.1.1 with eclipse luna in windows 64 bit

[This is my folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBTJ3.png)

Comment: First you need to rename your class according to java naming convention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: all is there according :(

Comment: should i compile it to class file and add in project ? cause my <%@ page import="java.util.List" %> is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested the shared code.Its working fine.

Do a clean build and try to run.There is no issue.

The code in my case

**obj.java**

```
package com.test;

public class obj {
    public String nameOwener(){
        return "mani";
    }

}
```

**test.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.test.obj" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        obj fooBar = new obj();
        System.out.println("Name is "+fooBar.nameOwener());
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
Name is mani
```

Comment: Yes I also tested it and it works but surprise is that it doesnt work on eclipse but runs awesome in netbeans :)     Whatever it is... My problem is solved....  Thanks for reply you all guys....

Comment: Thanks, It really helped